# ¿Puedo definir los estados de una máquina de estado finito en un arreglo para reducir código?

Tags: verilog

Tengo que realizar una máquina de estados finitos en verilog HDL con 8 estados. Se dispone de una señal UP/DOWN que:

Si UP/DOWN = 1 ==> S1-S2-S3...S8 (Cuenta ascendente)

Si UP/DOWN = 0 ==> S1-S8-S7...S2 (Cuenta descendente)

Lo he programado de la siguiente manera. Pongo el código del programa que recorre hasta el estado 4, hasta el estado 8 sigue el mismo proceso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible definir definir los estados como un vector S[7:0] y avanzar de estado mediante un bucle y de esta manera ahorrar en código?

Subo imagen de como tengo definidos los estados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola drqteruel, Bienvenido a SO en Español, **una recomendación**, intenta no poner tu codigó en imagen, ya que les es mas dficil a los miembros poder probar tu codigo, o incluirlo en su respuesta. Siempre es mejor colocar el codigó y formatearlo

Comment: Buenos días. Muchas gracias por la recomendación, lo tendré en cuenta. Es la primera vez que hago uso del foro despues de un tiempo leyendo. Por lo que veo también se ha cambiado el título.

Comment: Si, regularmente los miembros de la comunidad, tratan de modificar las preguntas para que puedan ser alcanzadas por la mayor cantidad de usuarios, asi es mas probable que obtengas mejores respuestas mas rapido :)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que no lo hayas hecho con un contador porque has codificado los estados en Gray.

Meter los estados en una tabla probablemente confunda al sintetizador (si es que pretendes que este código se sintetice) y no pueda aplicar optimizaciones. Por ejemplo, el sintetizador podría elegir cambiar la codificación de Gray a one-shot.

En System Verilog tienes la cláusula `enum` para definir estados más fácilmente (no se les pone valor, sino que eso lo realiza el propio sintetizador), pero en Verilog la opción que he visto siempre es enumerar los estados con un param o con `define, como en tu segunda imagen.

De todas formas...

> Mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible definir definir los estados como un vector
>   S[7:0] y avanzar de estado mediante un bucle y de esta manera ahorrar
>   en código?

Avanzar con un bucle ¿cómo? En código diseñado para ser sintetizado no hay bucles, salvo los que se usan para repetir lógica. Sólo se me ocurre algo como esto:

```
reg [2:0] state = 3'd0;
reg [2:0] states[0:7];
reg [2:0] idxstate = 3'd0;
initial begin
  states[0] = 3'b000;
  states[1] = 3'b001;
  states[2] = 3'b011;
  states[3] = 3'b010;
  states[4] = 3'b110;
  states[5] = 3'b111;
  states[6] = 3'b101;
  states[7] = 3'b100;
end

always @(posedege clk) begin
  if (updown == 1'b1)
     idxstate <= idxstate + 3'b001;
  else
     idxstate <= idxstate + 3'b111;
  state <= states[idxstate];
end

always @* begin
  case (state)
  ... etc ...
  endcase
end
```

Esto hace que `state` vaya tomando los valores del array en el orden ascendente o descendente, pero fíjate que en este código aparecen redundancias: usamos un registro para el estado, pero otro más para indicar el índice al array donde se guarda el estado. Es decir, el índice al estado vale en realidad como estado.

Si se va a usar siempre código Gray, puede cambiarse este código por el siguiente (que es el que generaría un sintetizador verdaderamente inteligente):

```
reg [2:0] idxstate = 3'd0;
reg [2:0] state = 3'd0;

always @(posedege clk) begin
  if (updown == 1'b1)
     idxstate <= idxstate + 3'b001;
  else
     idxstate <= idxstate + 3'b111;
  // state recibe el valor de idxstate pasado a Gray
  state <= {idxstate[2], idxstate[2]^idxstate[1], idxstate[1]^idxstate[0]}; 
end

always @* begin
  case (state)
  ... etc ...
  endcase
end
```